# realloc does not work while passing an array by reference

Tags: segmentation-fault, realloc

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct{
  int *array;
  int n;
}foo;


void bar(foo **a, int i)
{
  a[i]->array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
  *a = realloc(*a,(i+2)*sizeof(foo));
}

int main() {
  foo *a;
  int i;
  a = malloc(sizeof(foo));
  for (i=0; i<2; i++) bar(&a, i);
}
```

During my second iteration (i=1) I get segmentation fault in command

`a[i]->array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);`

How is this possible? The array must have 2 elements because I have done realloc and I have passed the array by reference. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, a declaration like **foo **a** is mildly ambiguous in that it doesn't actually tell you how many **foo *** values there are or for each **foo *** value how many **foo** values that **foo *** points to.  This must be inferred from context.  For example, argc in main tells one how many pointers to expect argv to point to.

In your concise minimal reproducible example, when bar() is called, the **a** argument to **bar()** always points to a single **foo *** (allocated on the stack in main).  The apparent intent of the program is that the single **foo *** in main should point to an array with one or more instances of **foo**.

The following line is assuming that the argument **a** to **bar()** points to an array at least i+1 **foo *** pointers.  It happens to work when i == 0 because there always is exactly one **foo ***, but doesn't work when i > 0 because there is never more than one **foo ***.

```
a[i]->array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

To fix that statement so that it always uses the first, and only, foo*, and expects that single foo* to point to an array of foo change it to the following:

```
(*a)[i].array = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```